# How to prevent AppleScript confirmation from appearing when using Quicksilver trigger?

Tags: applescript, quicksilver

When I launch this simple AppleScript from Finder or by using the standard Quicksilver panel selection, it runs without confirmation.

```
tell application "Flux"
    if it is running then
        quit application "Flux"
    else
        launch application "Flux"
    end if
end tell
```

But if I launch it with a Quicksilver trigger, it opens a confirmation dialog asking "Are you sure you want to run this script?"  How do I prevent this confirmation dialog from appearing?

Comment: I can’t get the dialogue to appear at all. I tried:

  * Saving as a script and using Quicksilver’s “Run” action
  * Saving as an application and using the “Open” action
  * Entering the script as text in the first pane and using the “Run as AppleScript” action

In all cases, the thing just runs silently. I used TextMate, since I don’t have Flux, but that seems unlikely to matter.

Comment: @RobMcBroom Using OSX 10.9?

Comment: Yes, I’m using 10.9.